# I need to identify this text format

Tags: text, file-format

I have a document with a bunch of contact info. But I don't know what format it is. Does anyone recognize it? I tried naming as .rtf but it doesn't change it.

```
\.br\Phone:\.br\12345678\.br\\.br\Description:\.br\this is some description\.br\\.br\
```

There are obviously line breaks of some sort similar to HTML but I am not sure!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.healthintersections.com.au/?page_id=441

the type is from HL7 format. and defined as:

HL7 v2 FT Type